# Django documentation error?

Tags: django

In official Django docs, section about exclude from querysets (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exclude), there is an explanation of several queries:

This example excludes all entries whose pub_date is later than 2005-1-3 AND whose headline is “Hello”:

```
Entry.objects.exclude(pub_date__gt=datetime.date(2005, 1, 3), headline='Hello')
```

In SQL terms, that evaluates to:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE NOT (pub_date > '2005-1-3' AND headline = 'Hello')
```

This example excludes all entries whose pub_date is later than 2005-1-3 OR whose headline is    “Hello”:

```
Entry.objects.exclude(pub_date__gt=datetime.date(2005, 1, 3)).exclude(headline='Hello')
```

In SQL terms, that evaluates to:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE NOT pub_date > '2005-1-3'
AND NOT headline = 'Hello'
```

Note the second example is more restrictive.

Last one is not clear to me. I don't see difference between the first one and the second one, can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the part "Note the second example is more restrictive.", perhaps a more mathematical approach can help you:

`NOT (pub_date > '2005-1-3' AND headline = 'Hello')`

can be translated to:

`NOT pub_date > '2005-1-3' OR NOT headline = 'Hello'`

which compared to:

`NOT pub_date > '2005-1-3' AND NOT headline = 'Hello'`

is less restrictive as you want either part of the `OR` to be true, that is - `A OR B` is less restrictive than `A AND B`.

Back to the docs, in the first case you exclude those who fit both the restrictions at the same time. While in the second you exclude those who fit the first restriction and from that you exclude those who fit the second one, that is - you exclude those who fit either one of the restrictions.

@OP's comment: Imagine we have four items AA, AB, BB and CC. If we say:

```
Item.objects.filter(name_startswith='A', name_endswith='B')
```

The result will be {AB}. Naturally if we say:

```
Item.objects.exclude(name_startswith='A', name_endswith='B')
```

The result will be {AA, BB, CC}, because we want to exclude only those who start with 'A' AND end with 'B'. The next one:

```
Item.objects.exclude(name_startswith='A')
```

will result in {BB, CC}. However when we **chain** another exclude:

```
Item.objects.exclude(name_startswith='A').exclude(name_endswith='B')
```

we're practically saying `THE_RESULT_OF_THE_FIRST_EXCLUDE.exclude(name_endswith='B')`. That is:

```
{BB, CC}.exclude(name_endswith='B')
```

Which will return {CC}. Unlike `filter`, where

```
Item.objects.filter(<condition_1>).filter(<condition_2>)
```

bears the same result as:

```
Item.objects.filter(<condition_1>, <condition_2>)
```

Exclude's are **chained**. It is similar to boolean operations:

NOT(A AND B) = NOT A OR NOT B
NOT(A OR B) = NOT A AND NOT B

Comment: Thx for the answer, then comes another question: why is Entry.objects.exclude(pub_date__gt=datetime.date(2005, 1, 3)).exclude(headline='Hello') is equal to SELECT ...
WHERE NOT pub_date > '2005-1-3'
AND NOT headline = 'Hello', i can't realy understand why is there AND in sql, and not OR?

Answer (score 2):

The first example creates a nested sub-expression, while the second creates two separate expressions.